# RECURSIVE query in MySQL similar to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table where I want to get all rows recurrsively based on `id` and `upline_id` (parent id) fields. This has been done in PostgreSQL like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE downlines(id, number, upline_id, first_name, last_name, level) AS (
  SELECT id, number, upline_id, first_name, last_name, 1
  FROM mytable
  WHERE id = 2061
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, a.number, a.upline_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, d.level + 1
  FROM mytable a, downlines d
  WHERE a.upline_id = d.id
)

SELECT * from downlines
```

However I am new to MySQL and cannot figure out how to convert above query into MySQL version. I found this for MySQL:

```
select  *
from    (select * from agents order by id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '2061') initialisation
where   find_in_set(upline_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

However results do not match, in MySQL version many rows are missing.

Can anybody tell how do I convert above PostgreSQL query to MySQL to get recursive/hierarchical (n/unknown depth) data?

Comment: There's no recursion in MySQL, but every recursion can be rewritten using a LOOP in a Stored Procedure. Start with `level = 0`, insert/select the base query into a temp table. Then ins/sel the recursive part joining to the temp table  `AND level = 0`. Check if activity count > 0, if yes, increase `level` and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL not supports `WITH RECURSIVE`. But to round this problem you can instead use `session variable(starting with @)` to hold the values in query.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.number, a.upline_id, 
         a.first_name, a.last_name, 
         @level:=@level+1 as `level`
FROM mytable a inner join
(
    SELECT id, number, upline_id, first_name, last_name
    FROM mytable WHERE id = 2061
) d on a.upline_id = d.id  ,(select @level:=0) as p ;
```

Comment: Is `temp` supposed to be `downlines` here?

Comment: @mu is too short: MySQL not supports creating temporary table using `temp` word.

Comment: You're creating a temporary table named `temp` but `downlines` is in the query. And will that actually recurse?

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: @Code-Monk: Thanks but it shows less rows so i assume it does not perform exactly like postgre version :(

Comment: @dev02: It will be good If you can share sample data and required output with table structure,then I will make it to give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working query for single table downline with parent id field in mysql

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.number, T2.first_name, T1.lvl AS level
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user_parent_id, _id) GROUP BY user_parent_id) AS user_parent_id,
        @r AS _idn,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 2061, @l := 0) vars,
        users h) T1
JOIN users T2
ON (FIND_IN_SET(T2.user_parent_id, T1._id))
 ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```